# Emulating successful send via phpmailer ($mail->Send())

Tags: php, phpmailer

When I'm building and testing my website on local server, I would like to emulate successful sending via phpmailer, so I avoid actually sending emails.

I normally use `if ($mail->Send()) { the mail was sent, now do this }`.

For local testing I think the best would be to skip the whole phpmailer inclusion, instead of adding a lot of if statements etc.

But skipping phpmailer would then cause php to complain about `$mail->Send()`, `$mail->addAddress('emailaddress')` etc.

How could I fake the function (or object/class) so that calls to `$mail->Send()` are always true, and the rest `$mail->something()` etc. are just ignored/true, so that no email is sent?

Comment: Extend PHPMailer and override send() so it does not actually invoke preSend() or postSend() and always returns true. Based on your environment, use the original or the dummy class.

Comment: What Marekful said. Alternatively, launch a local fake mail server, like smtpsink that's bundled with postfix - that's what the PHPMailer test suite does.

Answer (score 2):

Extend the PHPMailer class and override the `public function send()`.

```
class UnitTestMailer extends PHPMailer {

    public function send() {
        return $this;
    }

}

class User {
   public function __construct(PHPMailer $mailer) {
      $this->mailer = $mailer;
   }

   public function sendActiviation() {
      return $this->mailer->send();
   }
}

// ... somewhere in your test
public function test_if_from_is_properly_set() {
    // ...
    $user = new User(new UnitTestMailer);
    // ...
    $mailer = $user->sendActivation();
    $this->assertEquals($expectedFrom, $mailer->From);
}
```

Comment: Ok that would skip sending the mail and make `$mail->Send()` true? Can your code be put somewhere outside of phpmailer?

Comment: You can do whatever you want in that `send()` method. You can return true/false or the whole object to check if a header was set properly or whatever. Of course you can put it where ever you want. You just need the PHPMailer to be included or even better autoloaded.

Comment: Hm ok, I need to think this over more. I just tested your extension (with `return true;`) and phpmailer still sends the mail because nothing has changed. What was already true is now just always true ;) So I need to add/change something so that it won't send. Can't I just skip loading phpmailer and replace it with a small fake class that is true for every call to it?

Comment: @mowgli you have to instantiate `UnitTestMailer` instead of `PHPMailer`

Comment: @NikitaLeshchev Thanks for your edit but I wouldn't do it like that but rather explicitly inject the UnitTestMailer when testing rather than the normal mailer. The mailer shouldn't know about things like production or development.

Comment: What would the code for "don't send any email but return true" look like added in the extension?

Comment: @steros agreed, it was just a raw example. The right way is make the Mailer as a service, rename this env var to `MAILER_SEND_EMAILS` and pass it's value to the Mailer's constructor, assign to private variable and then check it inside `send()` function

Comment: @steros I see your edited answer, but don't quite understand ;). Would it make $mail->Send() = true without sending anything, in all cases?

Comment: If you just want it to be true, just return true.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why emulate?

I use INI files to provide configuration variables for PHPMailer depending on the environment. Live obviously has the server's mail settings. Local uses my Gmail account credentials to send mail.

You can have the best of both worlds :)

---

Keep a `config.ini` file for example somewhere in your working directory (I tend to use root but that's preference) and make sure it's in your `.gitignore` or similar. Your local version would look something like:

```
[PHPMailer Settings]
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_SMTPSECURE = "tls"
EMAIL_SMTPAUTH = "true"
EMAIL_USERNAME = "my_email@gmail.com"
EMAIL_PASSWORD = "my_password"
```

then in your PHP:

```
$ini = parse_ini_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/config.ini", true, INI_SCANNER_TYPED);

// use settings from INI file:

$foo = $ini['PHPMailer Settings']['EMAIL_HOST'];
$bar = $ini['PHPMailer Settings']['EMAIL_PORT'];
```

---

#### Security Bonus

Change the syntax of your INI file to look like the below and rename it to `config.ini.php`:

```
; <?php
; die();
; /*
[PHPMailer Settings]
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_SMTPSECURE = "tls"
EMAIL_SMTPAUTH = "true"
EMAIL_USERNAME = "my_email@gmail.com"
EMAIL_PASSWORD = "my_password"
; */ ?>
```

*(remember to use the new filename in your PHP code)*

PHP can still parse the settings, but if anyone tried to access the INI file it would be parsed as PHP comments and just show `";"`

Comment: Could you explain a little more about how exactly? I use config files too, for local vs live server settings. But my code on all pages refer to phpmailer and its functions etc. Also, I would like to avoid any email provider algorithm go "hmm same email content from different sources = this could be spam" ;)

Comment: @MacroMan If you have a proper test/dev server setup you have a mail catcher and thus there is no need for this if you want to actually test if mailing works. Plus the added security that none will ever really go out to the public.

Comment: @steros I use INI files for a whole array of different settings - this is just something else I do with it as they're a necessary part of the system for me anyway. From a developer perspective it's sometimes easier to do things like this for testing and debugging, particularly if you're using a L/WAMP stack on a local machine and working with other developers in the same boat.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and effort, but it's not an answer to my questions. It's more about how to handle config/ini files ;) I want phpmailer to return true while not sending any emails.

Comment: @mowgli because you stated `"For local testing I think the best would be to skip the whole phpmailer inclusion, instead of adding a lot of if statements etc."` my answer to that is, why not have PHPMailer actually just work in both environments? If you specifically don't want PHPMailer to send anything for some reason then fair enough I apologise as I misunderstood.

Comment: @MacroMan Your first suggestion to just use a testing email address locally is not bad though. That would take one small line of code to work fine. I will think about it. But I would prefer to have phpmailer not send out anything. Otherwise the recieving testing email address would also get flooded quickly while I'm working and testing ;) And would quickly be perceived as spam